# What Causes SQL Server To Gets Stuck in Restored State

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The company I work for will usually have a personal database for us that is a clone of the staging database. Sometimes I will need to blow away my database and restore it to the current version of the staging database, so the process by which I do this is:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the server
3. Open the Object Explorer
4. Expand the server tree node
5. Expand the Databases tree node
6. Right-click on my database
7. Click Delete (check the Close existing connections options)
8. Click OK
9. Right-click on the Databases tree node
10. Click Restore Database...
11. In the source database dropdown, select the staging copy
12. In the destination database combobox, change the value to be the name of my database
13. Click OK

The issue is that more often than not, the database gets stuck in a restored state. The issue is simple enough to resolve in that I can run the following query immediately following step 13:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE stagingdatabase WITH RECOVERY;
```

But preferably I'd like to know why it gets stuck in the restored state to begin with and see if there is something I can add to my list of steps to prevent it from getting stuck in the first place.

Comment: Presumably when you ran the `RESTORE` you selected `RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY` in the Recovery state in the dialogue box.

Comment: @Larnu - When I run steps 10 - 13, I keep the options as they're set by default. I double-checked the recovery state and it is `RESTORE WITH RECOVERY` by default and the checkboxes above that dropdown are all left unchecked.

Comment: Then the database would come out of recovery mode at the end of the `RESTORE`, @David .

Comment: When restoring a database, the state of the database must be in "restoring" because it will replay some last transactions that have data not yet writes into the datafile. This may be long sometime due to the lack of resources, like when you do it on a PC or a laptop  that have a limited RAM...

Comment: @SQLpro - it will basically stay in that state until I run the command. The longest I've left it was 2 days and it never came out. I don't think that it is the RAM because I just checked and I have 32 GB of installed memory with 31.8 GB as "usable". The only caveat is that the server in which the database resides does have quite a few databases (125 to be exact) and some of those could probably be deleted (old projects not supported anymore). Could that be an issue?

Comment: The duration can be due to the structure of transaction log, especially if there is many VLF. Just verify that point on the source instance with:  SELECT d.name, ls.total_vlf_count 
FROM   sys.databases AS d
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_log_stats(d.database_id) AS ls